# React Native TVOS Upgrade Issue: 'MinimumOSVersion' Missing in Info.plist Hermes Enabled

Tags: react-native, tvos, info.plist, react-native-hermes, itmstransporter

I'm woking on tv os app.I recently upgraded React Native TVOS from version 0.69.8-2 to 0.71.11. After the upgrade, I'm encountering an issue when trying to upload my IPA file to Transporter.

The error message I'm receiving is as follows:
Asset validation failed (90360)
Missing Info.plist value. A value for the key 'MinimumOSVersion' in bundle App-tvOS.app/Frameworks/hermes.framework is required. (ID: e1caf6cf-c500-40b1-9b63-0f2488fc9313)

Here is a snippet of my Podfile with Hermes enabled:
use_react_native!(
:path => config[:reactNativePath],
:hermes_enabled => true
)

I have tried several solutions including adding the 'MinimumOSVersion' key to the 'Info.plist' file  and cleaning/rebuilding the project, but none of these have resolved the issue.

Has anyone else encountered this problem and found a solution? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I want to upload react native my app on transporter.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to version `0.71.13-1` which fixes this issue.

Read more about the issue here: https://github.com/react-native-tvos/react-native-tvos/issues/563